# PHP Imagick class not found

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, imagick

I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Imagick' not found
```

But I've installed Imagick:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

And I can see it in PHP info:

```
$ -i | grep Imagick 
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
```

I'm not importing or user `require_once` or anything like that in the script that uses it. I don't need to do that on my local version, I've just pushed this live and it's failing

Comment: Did you restart the web server after installing php5-imagick?

Comment: @VladimirKolesnikov, must have if it is in PHPInfo..

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, not necesasarily — `php -i` invokes `php-cli`; if the web server has not been restarted, it won't see the new module.

That is, php-cli, php-cgi, php-fpm, Apache module etc are all different entities.

Comment: Oh yes.. sorry.. my bad.. I was thinking `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` haha .. even though the example was from the console.. it's late, I'm tired lol..

Comment: Oh god. I've restarted the server a million times today. Imagick was installed, has been for weeks, but I ran `sudo apt-get php5imagick` today, and must have not restarted after. I am such a moron. @VladimirKolesnikov please post an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the web server was restarted after installation of php-imagick.